# How to return bound column value in VBA OpenRecordSet?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm stuck on this problem and I think it may just be that I can't see the forest for the trees (i.e. I'm missing the obvious).

This is the concerning part of my code in my `MS Access` `VBA` function:

```
'...some setup stuff previously
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim cp_qry As DAO.QueryDef
Dim cp_rst As DAO.Recordset

'Customer & Product collection
Dim cp_info As Collection
Set cp_info = New Collection

Set db = CurrentDb
'Query
Set cp_qry = db.QueryDefs("CPDetails_ProductQuery")
'Parameters
cp_qry.Parameters("input_id") = cForm.ProductID
'Open recordset
Set cp_rst = cp_qry.OpenRecordset()

If cp_rst.EOF Then GoTo Err_NoDetails

For Each x In cp_rst.Fields
    'next line for testing purposes
    If x.Name = "Model" Then MsgBox x.Value(0)
    If IsNull(x.Value) Then
        cp_info.Add "", x.Name
    Else
        'MsgBox (x.Name & ": " & x.Value)
        cp_info.Add x.Value, x.Name
    End If
    Next

cp_rst.Close
Set cp_rst = Nothing

MsgBox cp_info.Item("Model")

db.Close
'...more stuff dealing with results afterwards
```

This runs and returns almost exactly what I want.

My problem is that in the tables being queried by `CPDetails_ProductQuery` (which combines the customer and product details for the related issue for my convenience here) has a field for the `Model` of the product, which is a combobox querying the `ModelList` table. So the `Model` field has two columns: `ID` and `Model`. `Model` is the bound column and when I run the query normally this shows up fine - it is referenced without a problem elsewhere, but when I retrieve the recordset here I only get the numerical `ID` value, rather than the text value from the second (bound) column. Is this for some reason not possible in VBA? I created the query specifically for this function, so is there a property setting in the query where I can tell it to just retrieve the `Model` value and ignore the `ID`?

I hope I have made myself clear. If anyone has any ideas, help would be greatly appreciated so I can move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to join in `ModelList` in your query, and return `ModelList.Model` instead of the model you were normally returning.

Lookup fields are purely GUI things. Underlying data will always contain the value stored in the table, instead of the looked-up value. If you want to return the looked-up value, you will always have to join in your lookup table in the query.

(Of course there is `DLookUp`, but using it will have a major performance impact)

Comment: Ah ok. I was thinking that might be the solution, but I was puzzled by the behaviour as it seemed like the lookup field and bound column should work. I have used them in my forms without a problem, but if it is as you say and it is purely GUI, then that would explain that. Thanks